# Livepatch error: ...use of closed network connection

Tags: networking, canonical-livepatch

I am running a Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS server for Seafile in my local home network. I recently installed Livepatch with no errors and running

```
canonical-livepatch status
```

produces output showing a recent "last-check", "running" as true, "checkState" as checked and "patchState" as nothing-to-apply. The kernel is 4.15.0-52.56-generic.

All seems fine however I get an error in the logs of

```
while starting HTTP server: accept unix /var/snap/canonical-livepatch/77/livepatchd-priv.sock: use of closed network connection
```

Is this anything to be concerned about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've noticed the same errors. Looking more at the logs it seems that this error only occurs when doing a reboot. Livepatch tries to access a closed network connection because the network is being taken offline before the livepatch snap is stopped.
It shouldn't cause you any problems since running `canonical-livepatch status` gives you:

*running: true*
*checkState: checked*

You might also notice some warnings when your network is down:

> canonical-livepatch[1001]: during refresh: cannot check: cannot send status to server: cannot send request: Put https://livepatch.canonical.com/api/machine/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: dial tcp: lookup livepatch.canonical.com: no such host

I've removed them from my logs by adding the following to the top of `/etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf`

```
## Stop logging canonical-livepatch errors during reboot:
:msg, contains, "livepatchd.sock: use of closed network connection" stop
:msg, contains, "livepatchd-priv.sock: use of closed network connection" stop

## Stop canonical-livepatch logging warnings when network down:
if $programname == 'canonical-livepatch' then {
*.=warn stop
}
```

If you run `grep canonical-livepatch /var/log/syslog | less` you can see what it is doing:

> **Begin reboot**
>   canonical-livepatch[1008]: stopping client daemon
>   canonical-livepatch[1008]: stopping service "mitigation loop"
>   canonical-livepatch[1008]: service "mitigation loop" stopped
>   systemd[1]: Stopping Service for snap application canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd...
>   canonical-livepatch[1008]: stopping service "socket servers"
>   **Errors occur**
>   canonical-livepatch[1008]: while starting HTTP server: accept unix /var/snap/canonical-livepatch/81/livepatchd.sock: use of closed network connection
>   canonical-livepatch[1008]: while starting HTTP server: accept unix /var/snap/canonical-livepatch/81/livepatchd-priv.sock: use of closed network connection
>   canonical-livepatch[1008]: service "socket servers" stopped
>   canonical-livepatch[1008]: stopping service "refresh loop"
>   canonical-livepatch[1008]: service "refresh loop" stopped
>   canonical-livepatch[1008]: client daemon stopped
>   **After reboot livepatch comes back online here**
>   systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for canonical-livepatch, revision 81...
>   systemd[1]: Mounted Mount unit for canonical-livepatch, revision 81.
>   systemd[1]: Started Service for snap application canonical-livepatch.canonical-livepatchd.
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: starting client daemon version 9.4.1
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: starting svc "mitigation loop"
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: service "mitigation loop" started
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: starting svc "socket servers"
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: service "socket servers" started
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: starting svc "refresh loop"
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: service "refresh loop" started
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: client daemon started
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: Client.Check
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: Checking with livepatch service.
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: updating last-check
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: touched last check
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: No updates available at this time.
>   canonical-livepatch[967]: No payload available.

Comment: I can see the same pattern of events on my server when I look at "logs" using cockpit. For some reason I don't see the "errors" I posted about in syslog.  Thanks for looking at this its good to know its not a problem

Comment: They might be set up to log somewhere else. You can also run `snap logs canonical-livepatch` to check if livepatch is updating but that will only show the most recent logs. So you probably won't see those errors there either.